# Where does BasicTeX put the texmf directory on OSX?

Tags: packages, installing, mac

I have just installed [BasicTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) on OSX 10.5 and I'm trying to locate the `texmf` directory to copy the [`llncs`](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) (LaTeX `.cls` and `.sty` files) folder into. 
According to the install log the location should be `~/Library/texmf`, but this folder does not exist.

So where are the packages stored on OSX?

Background: the [`llncs`](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) package is not in the usual repositories so it cannot be installed with any of the package-management tools. On the Windows machine at work I use MikTeX and installed the package manually by copying it to the `texmf` directory and updating the DB as explained in [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows).

Comment: The directory is not created as the installer doesn't touch users' homes. Just create it: open your home Library folder and hit the "New folder" menu entry, naming the new folder `texmf`.

Comment: I created the texmf directory and put the package there, but latex can't find it.

Comment: You have to create the entire path `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/llncs`, that is, a folder `llncs` inside `latex` inside `tex` inside `texmf`, and finally put the `llncs.cls` file in the last folder. There's nothing else to do.

Comment: Thank you! It works like charm. Meta: can i mark comment as an answer somehow?

Comment: Is this still correct? I am running BasicTex 2020 on 10.15 and would like to do this with [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) and [hyphenat](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat?lang=en). To my knowledge, these do not come with the small distribution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "personal tree" on Mac OS X is rooted in the `Library` folder for each user. However the installer doesn't touch the users' home directories, so the

```
~/Library/texmf
```

folder has to be created. Inside it one has to rebuild the usual TDS structure, so `llncs.cls` should go into

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/llncs
```

and all folders must be created manually. So, open `Library` in your folder, create `texmf`, open it, create `tex`, open it, create `latex`, open it, create `llncs` and finally put `llncs.cls` in the last created folder.

This is necessary in order that the TeX programs can correctly find the file.

Note that no "hashing" operation needs to be performed: the "personal tree" is always searched, since it's assumed not to be very big.

---

On GNU/Linux systems one should omit the "Library" level.